# SPD 2007 custom workflow sending duplicate Emails

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Hope you can help:

We've built a rather simple, custom workflow in SPD which is connected to a custom list.  In the list there is a Status column, with a choice-drop down and one of the values being "Complete".

For the Workflow Start Options, we selected both:
- "when new item is created" and 
- whenever an item is changed.

We built the workflow with two steps:

**Step 1**:

(Condition): When a new item has been created, (Action) Send an Email to "created by" (a "thank you for your submission..." )

**Step 2**:
(Condition - lookup) when the "Status" column equals "Complete" (Action) Send an email to "Created by"/User who created item ("your order is complete...").

Good news is, in testing we receive both the "Thank you" email when a new item is created and also the "order complete" email when we update the status field to "Complete."  Bad news is if we update the record with other status values before marking it "Complete" ("Hold", etc), then the first "thanks for your submission" email is sent again to the 'created by' user.  As you can guess, they should only receive a total of two emails during the entire process.

Could this be because of the start option also being set to "change", even though we specified the parameters for the change?  Perhaps the two steps need to be defined as two separate workflows?  It seems simple and specific enough that they can be contained in the same workflow.

Appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that your email is probably being sent again because you have the workflow trigger on both create and change.  What you can do to isolate the create event is to only send that email conditionally when the "Created" date of the item is the same as the "Modified" date.  That will only occur when you initially create the item.  This will save you from having to create 2 separate workflows.